# How I can add padding to the Angular mat tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to style the tooltip dialog window - add paddings if to be precise.
Changing width and background color works good, but styling paddings is not working:
[image: no padding]

I adjust styles in my scss file:

```
::ng-deep .custom-tooltip {
  background-color: #265daf;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: small;
  padding-left: 20px;
  max-width: unset !important;
}
```

Are there any other ways to add padding to the tooltip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to replace :

```
padding-left: 20px;
```

with:

```
padding-left: 20px !important;
```